# Employee uploaded proprietary private repository on his github public account

Tags: data-leakage, git, github

A newly joined software engineer in our organization uploaded one of company's proprietary git repository on his personal Github public account, likely without nefarious intent.

How do I ensure this won't happen again in future? Apart from formal code of conducts, signing NDA etc. Are there any technical measures that can help (like firewalls etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Awareness will likely be your best bet

If a user attempts to push code to one of their repositories, thinking it's theirs (and not the company's), then any error saying the push request failed will likely cause them to try and "fix the issue" and not realize they are being protected from a mistake.

**Discuss the incident** with the programmer in question and ask them how it came to the circumstance. Keep in mind that the newly hired guy will likely feel *extremely* nervous, because joining and already causing a security incident doesn't make a good look. So make sure to make it known that it's not them getting investigated, it's the incident that is being investigated.

Then **identify what factors lead to this incident**. Is the onboarding process broken? There have been several incidents where newly hired developers attempted to bootstrap their dev environment and ran the setup script on the prod server instead of their local machine, wiping it completely. Or does the company workflow include personally-owned GitHub repositories? Is it perhaps "lived workflow" that employees want to work on their projects at home, so they clone them to private(?) GitHub repositories to bring their work home?

Next, **develop mitigation strategies** for these factors. If people feel like they have to circumvent company security controls to "get their work done", then you need to re-work your security controls. If the onboarding process makes sense only to the person who developed it, but not to new hires, then rework that process to prevent future mistakes.

---

Furthermore, while the technical mitigations mentioned in [Todd A. Jacobs' answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/261181/163495) are worth implementing, I believe they should be seen as a secondary measure and not as something to be relied upon.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Address the issue within your current incident response process. Then do a post-mortem to see if there were any additional controls that may have been applicable and could be implemented in the future.

Additionally, since the original question was edited—the original post posited an intentional breach by an active internal threat actor—it's worth noting that:

1. Education and awareness training are certainly useful tools in communicating about the security program.
2. Opening a dialog is always a great way of exploring the root cause of a breach, especially an unintentional one

but neither is operationally effective as an automatable detective or preventative control. While tools can't substitute for human judgment, human beings are often the weakest link in continuous operational enforcement. That is why continuously-operating automated controls to enforce policies and standards are often more effective in addressing this kind of accidental exfiltration issue than policies, non-disclosure agreements, or routine awareness training.

### Reframing the Issue

This isn't really "data leakage" as the original post (before it was edited) expressed it. This is really more within the domain of applying appropriate controls to your source code management system, as well as endpoint protection and data loss prevention (DLP) on your company-owned equipment.

If you're allowing people to use their own equipment, then you may have to apply other compensating controls, but the bottom line is that while you can *limit* accidental exposure you can never completely eliminate the risk of deliberate exposure from an active threat actor. That's just the reality of the information security domain.

### GitHub-Specific Controls

Per GitHub's page on [inherited fork permissions](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks/about-forks):

> Private forks inherit the permissions structure of the upstream or parent repository. This helps owners of private repositories maintain control over their code. For example, if the upstream repository is private and gives read/write access to a team, then the same team will have read/write access to any forks of the private upstream repository. Only team permissions (not individual permissions) are inherited by private forks.

There is also a page dedicated to explaining how to [manage the forking policy for private repositories hosted by an organization](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-organization-settings/managing-the-forking-policy-for-your-organization) or for [specific repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/managing-repository-settings/managing-the-forking-policy-for-your-repository).

If you haven't set any controls on your organization's repositories, or your repositories are public, then focus on implementing those controls. If you have already implemented those controls, then you need to re-evaluate your threat model and design operationally-effective controls that address your real workflow. You may even need to change your workflows if adequate controls can't be applied.

Just remember that no individual control or set of controls is 100% guaranteed. You are *mitigating* risk by applying appropriate controls. There's no such thing as perfect security, especially when faced with deliberate insider threats or a failure to apply basic controls in the first place.

### Public Repository Scanning

While not really a preventative control, you might also consider applying detective controls such as scanning publicly-accessible code repositories on sites like GitHub or GitLab for specific SHAs, either directly or via a search engine. That won't *prevent* people from making a private repository public, but it can at least provide some insight into whether a specific commit, blob, or tree is publicly available.

For example, given a recent commit on the [Ruby 3.1 branch](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/ruby_3_1), you might search for the short or long SHA of the commit like so:

- [53f5fc4](https://github.com/search?q=53f5fc4)
- [53f5fc4236a754ddf94b20dbb70ab63bd5109b18](https://github.com/search?q=53f5fc4236a754ddf94b20dbb70ab63bd5109b18)

Finding a good search on search engines (which may treat SHA hashes as stopwords or otherwise choose not to index them) is harder, but one supposes it would be possible if you invest the time. However, even within Git web-based user interfaces there are lots of caveats to this type of approach, including (but not limited to):

1. The inability to search within private repositories outside your organization.
2. Lots of false positives on abbreviated hashes.
3. Lots of false positives for common trees such as a freshly-initialized project skeleton.

However, this may be useful *within* an organization's self-hosted repositories, or within common public repositories using their own search features. You may find other ways to perform OSINT as well, but avoid tinfoil hat territory. Your best bet is still to **apply basic controls and data-loss prevention techniques**, and then **address policy violations in accordance with your organization's incident response process**.

Comment: I believe this is a very good answer. No idea why anyone would downvote it...

Comment: Thanks your inputs Jacobs, some of these things are certainly worth looking at. But as per MechMK1 answer, I believe Awareness is the best bet to prevent this issue.

Comment: @Abhinav Awareness training is important, but isn't an *active* control. The original question described an active breach that wouldn't have been detected or prevented by training alone. While training is important it wouldn'tt have been operationally effective in preventing or detecting such a breach, regardless of whether it was deliberate or accidental. One should always consider the threat model, as well as design effectiveness and operational effectiveness, when crafting controls. That doesn't make the training answer wrong; just insufficient by itself IMHO. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the size of the organization, you can do things like purchase a Cloud Proxy solution. ZScaler, McAfee and there are others. Various cloud proxies often install an agent on the desktop that redirects web requests out through a cloud from individual machines. Once those requests go out through the cloud you can enforce policies as to whether the user can browse too... and block things. So one of the things you could deny access to is public or private github instances. That's one solution there are others.